# Auto resize not working in input text area in primefaces 5.3.6

Tags: jquery, html, css, jsf, primefaces

I created a p:textArea with autoResize=true (default).The text area should start re-sizing once the content exceeds the described row size. 
It is not re-sizing and scroll bar is also not showing up, instead the text is stacking up and the height of the input text area also not changing.

```
<p:inputTextarea id="bldgNotes" rows="3" cols="40" counter="counter" maxlength="2550" style="width:96%" counterTemplate="{0} characters remaining." autoResize="true" value="#{buildingBean.originalBuilding.buildingNote}" />
```

[This image shows that auto resize is not happening](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7O3sg.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

This is a css issue. Check the HTML output and act accordingly.

mouse on element -> right click -> inspect and check around the classes there might be something like this :

```
 resize: none;
 or 
 overflow:
```